# File Upload with Progress React

Tags: reactjs, file, file-upload, upload, antd

I am trying to Upload the file and save the file in the state of the component as file.originFileObj, I want my output to be like while uploading the file the progress should be Shown

[image: for Uploading]

And while uploading the file after selection

[image: After]

I have used antd upload but it does not provide the round and file size status and that kind of percentage, I have also tried simple HTML input tag but it also does not work, the [last thing](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-58128062-upload-progress) I got near to the requirement was uploading the file to certain URL and displaying that progress but I need to be saved in my state and uploading status to be shown as shown in the image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kSsv.png)

Answer (score 3):

add options to your api request

```
    const options = {
        onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
            const {loaded, total} = progressEvent
            let percent = Math.floor(loaded * 100 / total)
            this.setState({
                uploadPercentage: percent
            })
        },
    }
```

Comment: As asked there is no API request involved, Just upload a pdf file and store it to the state of Component